# Samsung Galaxy Y asking to install CDC ACM DATA?

Tags: connection-issues, usb-drivers, samsung-galaxy-y

I have connected my Samsung Galaxy Y mobile with Windows XP (64 bit) operating system. It is asking me to install the **CDC ACM Data.** I have selected the 'install automatically' option, but it is saying that it can't install the software. Where can I find the software? I have searched a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/abstract-control-model-samsung-galaxy/b34228af-aaa1-48ff-b221-761a3586a54b) they say, installing Samsung Kies should solve the problem.
I haven't tried it yet, but it is available on [Samsung's official website](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/global) for their various phone models.